# Jobs opening for data scientist

Tags: data-request, time-series

Is there data regarding the number of job openings for data scientist/ data engineers and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of publicly available datasets. On the other hand, most availabnle statistics are computed on data obtained by web scraping job ads on the most common recruitment websites. I would suggest you taking the second path, as their number (and description) changes too rapidly anyway.